# scrollTop() with setInterval between positions doesnt visibly hold a scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to have a web page scroll up and down from 0 to the bottom of the screen (0-1080) according to an input. As a proof of concept **I wanted the page to ping/pong between two scroll positions over and over on a loop and have it actually scroll to that position and visibly hold it**. What happens is that it doesn't appear to move/scroll but sometimes the page flickers and if i scroll up/down it will immediately scroll to the bottom on the next setInterval cycle update.

```js
var switchTest = true;

function switcher() {
  if (switchTest == true) {
    $(window).scrollTop(0);
  } else {
    $(window).scrollTop(1080);
  }
  
  switchTest = !switchTest;
}

window.setInterval(function() {
  switcher();
}, 500);
```

```css
.div1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a small [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/81qa4n7f/) where the problem does not appear. It just scrolls up then down the up again in a 500 milliseconds cycle.

The html and css are very straighforward in order to show that it is indeed scrolling:

```
<div id="top">
top
</div>
<div id="middle">
middle1
<br>
middle2
<br>
middle3
<br>
middle4
<br>
middle5
<br>

</div>
<div id="bottom">
bottom
</div>

#top {
  height:2em;
  width:100%;
  background-color:blue;
  position:absolute;
}

#middle {
  background-color:grey;
  height:1500px;
}

#bottom {
  height:2em;
  width:100%;
  background-color:green;
  position:absolute;  
  bottom:0;
}
```

Have a look if it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have smooth scroll then you should use `animate` instead of `scrollTop`. Also you can optimize your `switcher` like below.

In `animate` first parameter is `{scrollTop: scroll}` 2nd parameter is `animation time`.

Try it below.

```js
var switchTest = true;

function switcher() {
  let scroll = switchTest ? 0 : 300;
  $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: scroll}, 500, 'swing');
  switchTest = !switchTest;
}

var x = setInterval(switcher, 1000)
```

```css
.div1 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: green;
}

.div2 {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
<div class='div1'></div>
<div class='div2'></div>
```